# How to create a context to hold informations between executions in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I want to hold some informations when some execution is running like CorrelationId, I tried to create a static class with an AsyncLocal object like this:

```cs
public static class InternalContext
    {
        private static readonly AsyncLocal<Dictionary<string, string>> InternalContextHolder =
            new AsyncLocal<Dictionary<string, string>>() { Value = new Dictionary<string, string>() };

        private static Dictionary<string, string> ContextHolder => InternalContextHolder.Value ??= new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public const string CORRELATION_ID_KEY = "correlationId";

        public static string CorrelationId
        {
            get
            {
                if (!ContextHolder.TryGetValue(key, out string currentValue))
                {
                    ContextHolder[CORRELATION_ID_KEY] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                }

                return ContextHolder[CORRELATION_ID_KEY];
            }
            set
            {
                ContextHolder[CORRELATION_ID_KEY] = value;
            }
        }

        public static void ResetContext()
        {
            CorrelationId = null;
            ContextHolder.Clear();
        }
    }
```

This is my code that call AWS SQS and get the messages in the queue:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<QueueMessage>> GetMessages() {
    var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
    {
        AttributeNames = new List<string> { "All" },
        MessageAttributeNames = new List<string>() { "All" },
        MaxNumberOfMessages = 1,
        QueueUrl = await amazonSQS.GetQueueUrlAsync("my-test-queue")
    };

    var result = await amazonSQS.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);
    // Convert result to internal QueueMessage object
    return result.ToQueueMessageList();
}

public string GetMessage()
{
    var message = GetMessages().FirstOrDefault();

    if (message != null)
    {
        InternalContext.CorrelationId = message.MessageAttributes["correlationId"];
    }

    return message?.body;
}
```

Then I have a `BackgroundService` running with this:

```cs
public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  var msg = GetMessage();
  // Couple HttpClient calls that is injecting the InternalContext.CorrelationId in the request headers for propagation

  // In the end of execution, reset the context to avoid "cached" values
  InternalContext.ResetContext();
}
```

So basically it works fine with 1 message in the queue, the biggest problem is that I'm now trying to get multiple messages from the SQS to make things faster, but when I try to process them in parallel the InternalContext get lost, using the same context instance for multiple Tasks, like this:

```cs
public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  IEnumerable<QueueMessage> messagesList = await GetMessages();

  var tasks = messagesList.Select(msg => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        InternalContext.CorrelationId = msg.MessageAttributes["correlationId"];
        // Couple HttpClient calls that is injecting the InternalContext.CorrelationId in the request headers for propagation

        // In the end of execution, reset the context to avoid "cached" values
        InternalContext.ResetContext();
    }));
    
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

But in this way above the InternalContext is conflicting with the Tasks, so it's like the first 3~5 messages send the CorrelationId from the first message, the messages 6~10 send the CorrelationId from the message X (they are "random").

So my guess is that this Context I create is not the best way to do it, but I have no idea how to deal with it.

The propose of this Context is to store data like the correlation id, trace id, and any other value I need, to send it to any request I make, doesn't matter if it's a HTTP call using HttpClient, or if I'm sending some message to a new Queue, or to a SNS topic, I kinda need to hold it's value while my code is executing and that it does't get lost with multi threading (which I tought AsyncLocal would help me with).

Comment: Dependency injection frameworks generally have a method called 'AddScoped<>'.  What this does is allow classes to be constructed separately from each other outside a scope, but shared if the instance is in the same scope.  A 'scope' in your case is a 'message'.  When you retrieve a message, you create a new scope, then call the DI to create the message processors (and its dependencies).  One of the dependencies can be what you are calling `InternalContext`, and this will be a different context per message, but shared between instances of the same message.

Comment: Will the AddScoped work even if those code are in different libraries? I guess I forgot to mention, those code are in different libs, I have my main project, the context one, the sqs one, the httpclient in another one, they all have the context as dependency, injecting them on each project using the AddScoped would work like this?

Comment: You only have one DI instance within an application, though.  You register with the DI to say "whenever any class wants an instance of the interface IXX this is the concrete XX to give them".  DI allows you to decouple the interface from the implementation.  The classes in your different libraries won't depend on the class `InternalContext`, they will depend on the interface `IInternalContext`.